# Conversão não é valida

Tags: c#, oracle, query

```
 public int ObterTotalAcessos()
    {
        int obtertotal = 0;

        using (var connection = ServiceLocator.ObterConexao())
        {
            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT SUM (ACESSOS) FROM USUARIO";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("total", obtertotal);

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                // o erro está aqui v

                  obtertotal = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }

        }

        return obtertotal;
    }
```

> Então galera, meu problema está ocorrendo dentro do (if). Exibe o erro: Conversão especificada invalida. Alguém tem noção o que posa ser?

Comment: Qual é a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Conversão especificada não é válida. O erro acontece dentro no IF

Comment: Vejo que você não é um usuário novo, então por favor dê uma lida nesta página: [ask] para melhorar a qualidade das tuas perguntas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Baseado nas informações que você postou, vejo duas situações possíveis que estejam ocasionando este problema:

**1)** O valor retornado pela tua query é nulo (`DbNull`). Para evitar este caso, vale a pena consistir:

```
if (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader[0] == DBNull.Value)
    {
        obtertotal = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        obtertotal = reader.GetInt32(0);
    }
}
```

**2)** O valor retornado pela tua query não é inteiro. Isso pode acontecer tendo em vista que o Oracle realiza conversões implícitas de tipo em valores agregados, operações aritméticas, etc. Para evitar contratempos neste caso, sugiro:

```
(...)
obtertotal = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
(...)
```